# How to change Windows 10 Device Manager so Arduino NANO COM3 can operate on COM4

Tags: arduino-nano

The Arduino ATmega328 NANO uses COM3 on my WINDOWS 10 computer,
but COM3 is NOT available.

QUESTION:
Please explain in detail how I can change this Arduino NANO
to operate on COM4

Comment: What do you mean com3 is not available...?

Comment: if COM3 is not available, then the Nano is not using COM3 or it is not plugged in or it has failed in some way

Answer (score 1):

In device manager, right click on the device and select "Properties". Then go to the tab "Connection properties" and click on "Advanced". There you can change the COM port number assignment for a particular device.

Answer (score 0):

In general, Windows assigns COM ports to USB devices when they are plugged in the first time.  If you have multiple USB sockets, the same physical device will be assigned a different COM port when plugged into different sockets.  Is it possible that you have changed your setup and are now using a different USB socket?  Try the others to see if that works.